# Circle sandwiched between two squares problem

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help with the problem attached? Many thanks in advance!
Regards,
P.

[image: Sandwiched circle]

[image: SanwichedHexagons]

This is what I've done so far

a)  The perimeter of square PQRS is 4 x 10 cm = 40 cm. The diagonal of square ABCD = side length x √2, so side length = diagonal /√2 = 10/√2 So, perimeter of square ABCD = 4 x 10/√2 = 40/√2 Perimeter lies between 40/√2 and 40 cm.

b)  The perimeter of the circle lies between 40/√2 and 40 cm. The area of a square is (perimeter/4)2. So, between 100/2 and 100, 50 and 100. As π = A/r² , it will lie between the ratio of area to radius squared, 2 and 4.

(beyond this I'm stuck!-- I cannot copy and get hexagons out of it. Hope someone helps with visualizing such sandwiched hexagons sketch --)

Comment: What is giving you trouble? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you! This is what I've tried so far. Beyond this I'm stuck:

a) The perimeter of square PQRS is 4 x 10 cm = 40 cm.
The diagonal of square ABCD = side length x √2, so side length = diagonal /√2  = 10/√2
So, perimeter of square ABCD = 4 x 10/√2 = 40/√2
Perimeter lies between 40/√2 and 40 cm.

b) The perimeter of the circle lies between 40/√2 and 40 cm.
The area of a square is (perimeter/4)2. So, between 10/√2 and 100, 50 and 100.
As π = A/r² , it will lie between the ratio of area to radius squared,  ??? and 100/25 (4)

Answer (score 2):

For a) everything is perfect so far, but you should simplify your surds! $\frac{40}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{20\cdot \sqrt{2}^2}{\sqrt{2}}=20\cdot \sqrt{2}$ which is the value you wanted.

For b), you have made this too complicated. Do not use the area formula, use the definition of $\pi$;
$$\pi=\frac{C}{d}$$
$$\frac{20\cdot\sqrt{2}}{2\cdot 5}<\pi<\frac{40}{2\cdot 5}$$
$$2\cdot\sqrt{2}<\pi<4$$
Of course, your working was fine with the other formula, but your result wasn't as strong (you gave a larger range for $\pi$; its minimum was $2$ instead of $2\sqrt{2}$).

Thanks to the wonderful Narasimham, you have a beautiful diagram for c). As for the perimeter of the hexagons [your exercise reads circumference of a hexagon, which is not correct: only round objects have circumferences], you need to find firstly the side length. Now if you are familiar with the geometry of a hexagon, you would recognise that a regular hexagon is made up of six equilateral triangles arranged in a pizza shape. For the smaller hexagon, since the radius is $5$cm, so will the side length. It's perimeter is six times that; $30$cm. For the larger hexagon we need to do more work, since now instead of the side length of the equilateral triangle being $5$cm, its height is $5$cm. Divide the triangle up into two so that you have a right angled triangle, you now know for a side length $x$, by Pythagoras:
$$\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+5^2=x^2$$
$$x=\frac{10}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{10\cdot\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}^2}=\frac{10\cdot\sqrt{3}}{3}$$
And then the perimeter is six times that; $20\cdot \sqrt{3}$cm.

d) Once again, we can use the definition of $\pi$;
$$\pi=\frac{C}{d}$$
$$\frac{30}{2\cdot 5}<\pi<\frac{20\cdot \sqrt{3}}{2\cdot 5}$$
$$3<\pi<2\cdot\sqrt{3}$$

If you are confused about how I got the side lengths of the hexagons, I will draw a diagram.